# Java getter setter method

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am making a program to calculate the cost of carpet fitting. I am struggling to write a setter getter message for the following variables... labourCharge, price and postCode.

Comment: You should initiallize variables in constructor right?

Comment: Share the class definition and attributs please

Comment: @GeorgeZ. this seems yo be a setter, or change the name to getLabourCharge

Comment: @azro lol, I did not notice. I just saw that and focused there. You are absolutely right. Plus, there are no arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a getter/setter inside the class only

```
public class CarpetCostEstimator {
   double price = -1.0;
   String postCode = "XXX-XXX";
   double labourCharge = 1.0;

   public double getPrice() {
      return price;
   }

   public void setPrice(double price) {
      this.price = price;
   }

   public String getPostCode() {
      return postCode;
   }

   public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
      this.postCode = postCode;
   }

   public double getLabourCharge() {
      return labourCharge;
   }

   public void setLabourCharge(double labourCharge) {
      this.labourCharge = labourCharge;
   }
}
```

Comment: hi, many thanks for your answer. so instead of this.price, this.postCode so on and so forth I should change it to the above...double price, string postcode.public class CarpetCostEstimator
{
   // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
   double price;
   double labourCharge;
   String postCode;

Comment: You can access in a way CarpetCostEstimator obj = new CarpetCostEstimator(); obj.setPrice(10.90) and get using getter Double priceis = obj.getPrice()

Comment: hi how would I test it. for example how would I create an object of the class CarpetCostEstimator, passing it the value 4.0 for the labour charge. thanks

Comment: send some details about OUWorkspace class what it is?

Comment: please read last comment

Comment: CarpetCostEstimator obj = new CarpetCostEstimator(); obj.setPrice(10.90) and get using getter Double priceis = obj.getPrice()

Comment: so this is what I have so far and when I execute it it says, error class expected.   CarpetCostEstimator obj = new CarpetCostEstimator();
obj.labourCharge(4.0);
obj.getlabourCharge(double);

Comment: obj.labourCharge(4.0);  this function not in class there setLabourCharge method for setting labour charges

Comment: I didnt get that. How? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should write your code. Assuming that your class is CarpetCostEstimator. The constructor takes the three values of labourCharge, postCode and price and sets them as follows:

```
public CarpetCostEstimator(double labourCharge, String postCode, double 
    price)
 {
     this.price = price;
     this.postCode = postCode;
     this.labourCharge = labourCharge;
  }

 public double getLabourCharge()
  { 
     return this.labourCharge ;
  }


   public void setLabourCharge(double labourCharge){
          this.labourCharge = labourCharge
   }
```

In the above code, I've showed you how to put a setter and getter for labourCharge, you can do the same for the other properties of price and postCode.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij idea it is convenient to generate getter and setter by means of a combination alt+insert, at the expense of other studios I do not know